# How does this function take the argument if its not pushed into the stack?

Tags: assembly, x86, intel

I dont understand how does the function take the argument without pushing

```
push ebp
mov ebp, esp
and esp, 0FFFFFFF0h
sub esp, 20h
mov [esp+20h+var_20], offset aEnterX ; "Enter X:"
call _puts
```

Answer (score 2):

`var_20` is likely defined as -20h, so the `mov` instruction is actually accessing `[esp]`. This puts the argument at the expected location for the called function, but does not change the `esp` itself. This approach of argument passing is used by GCC since many years ago. Supposedly this used to be somewhat faster than pushing [in some cases](https://gcc.gnu.org/legacy-ml/gcc-patches/2014-01/msg00008.html), and also changing `esp` one time in the prolog makes the stack management easier for the compiler.